# Bootstrap Modal not getting validated and showing error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have gone through multiple links to validate modal and tried with the below code snippet.
I am not sure what is the issue the modal is not validated and error messages are not showing up.

Here is my HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target='#sendModal' type="button">Contact <span class="icon glyphicon "></span></button>   

        <div class="modal fade" id="sendModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h5 class="modal-title">Contact</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject">Subject :</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" type="text" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" id="check1"type="checkbox" name="sp[]" value="1" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="check1">
                        Check1
                    </label>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input " id="check2" type="checkbox" name="sp[]"value="2" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="check2">
                        Check2
                    </label>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btnSend" class="btn btn-primary">Send </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Javascript function to validate

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("#sendModal").validate({
            rules: {
                'sp[]': {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1
                },
                subject: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                'sp[]': "Please select atleast one type of check",
                    subject: "Please enter subject"
            }
        });

         $("#btnSend").click(function () {
         var isValid = $("#sendModal").validate();
         });
});
```

When i clicked on Send button,even though i did not enter `subject` text box or did not check any check box,the form is getting submitted with out showing error messages.

Please let me know how to show error message when user did not check any check box and did not enter subject and message should show in red font color below text box and check box.

Comment: Are you using jQueryValidation plug-in? Your syntax suggested it. Did you include the proper CDNs? Your HTML is also incomplete as there is no FORM tag anywhere.

Comment: Applying `validate()` to a `div` doesn't really make sense ... my guess is it should be applied to a `form`.

Comment: ... aaaand as is almost always the case with jQuery questions, there are duplicates if you look.  There are no new jQuery questions! :-)

Comment: @KaseyChang - I am using Jquery validation and included all the cdns. I am not using ,<form> tag as it is modal.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - I tried applying <form> tag ,but still form is submitting with out validating.

Comment: `I am not using ,<form> tag as it is modal` - I am not sure what you mean, you can use a form in a modal, and as the duplicate I linked shows, you need a form.  You are also calling it incorrectly - remove the click handler completely.  All you need is `$("#sendModal").validate({ ... });`. Check the duplicate, check the docs.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - Thanks for suggestion.Now after adding form tag it is getting validated.

Comment: Perhaps a better question was WHAT made you conclude that "because it's modal, I don't need FORM tags"? The proper way to do it was to use form tags, but set the target to nothing and JavaScript intercept the post action with preventdefault.

Comment: @AMDI no problem - I suggest you close this as a duplicate of the question I linked.

Answer (score -1):

you could always just add `required` attribute inside the input tags.